# How can i change the actual background of tabs in tkinter and not the background of the tab headers

Tags: python, tkinter

i am trying to style my application and i cannot seem to add a background color to my notebooks. I can only add the color to the tab header and not the body of each tab. Here is my code.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
root.title('FlashCop')
root.geometry('1000x750')
root.configure(bg='#5AC18E')
style = ttk.Style()

style.theme_create("cool", parent="alt", settings={
    "TNotebook": {"configure": {"background": '#5AC18E', "tabmargins": [2, 5, 2, 0]}},
    "TNotebook.Tab": {
        "configure": {"padding": [5, 1], "background": '#133337'},
        "map": {"background": [("selected", '#133337')],
                "expand": [("selected", [1, 1, 1, 0])], }}})

style.theme_use("cool")

rows = 0
while rows < 50:
    root.rowconfigure(rows, weight=1)
    root.columnconfigure(rows, weight=1)
    rows += 1

nb = ttk.Notebook(root)
nb.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=50, rowspan=49, sticky='NESW')

page1 = ttk.Frame(nb)
nb.add(page1, text='Create Tasks')
a = Label(page1, text="YeezySupply or Adidas", bg='#133337', fg='#5AC18E')
a.place(x=10, y=25)
site = Entry(page1, width=10, bg='#C0C0C0')
site.place(x=10, y=45)

page2 = ttk.Frame(nb)
nb.add(page2, text='Tasks')

page3 = ttk.Frame(nb)
nb.add(page3, text='Proxys')

page4 = ttk.Frame(nb)
nb.add(page4, text='Settings')

root.mainloop()
```

Is there a function that can change the background color of the body of each tab?

Comment: Have you tried adding a background to the individual frames?

Comment: ughh i feel like an idiot! Thank you! I forgot i was using frames!

Comment: Add `... settings={ "TFrame": {"configure": {"background": '#5AC18E'}}, ...`